# How to repair the leg of a computer chair

Tags: repair, furniture, plastic

I have an office computer chair whose leg broke, there is a huge crack along the plastic, and it bends, but its still attached. I tried using hot glue and duct tape, but it breaks apart again because of the down force twisting the plastic and sheering it.

Any idea how to fix this?[image: picture of chair leg when force is applied]

Comment: Go to a place that sells used office furniture (or a yard sale) and pick up an entire base that appears compatible with the rest of your chair. There's no saving this one, at least not in any practical and economically sensible manner.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing is probably most practical.

But if you really want to fix it, you need something to support the weight.  Tape and glue aren't going to do it. I would find a length of strong pipe (check the plumbing section at a home improvement store) that will fit nicely either inside the leg (if it is hollow) or over top of it.  Make the pipe fill/cover as much of the leg as possible.  Then attach with tape, glue, bolts, whatever - just to stop it from sliding out.

If the pipe fits snugly it should hold up fairly well.

Comment: Gave up and got a new chair. with legs made out of metal

Answer (score 0):

Basically it will never be as strong as new.
If you do want to pursue a fix I would suggest rotating (friction) welding with a dremel and plastic filament (preferably identical to the chair).
Or, another idea is to cast epoxy resin or polyester.

Answer (score 0):

Get a piece of sheet metal, the thickest stuff you can find that you still can readily bend.  Wrap the sheet metal around the leg, then secure with 3 or 4 spiral hose clamps.

You may want to apply some glue (Flex Glue or some such) under the metal before final installation.

Answer (score -1):

I have an identical chair with the exact same break on one of the legs. I attached the broken part to the base by zip ties, and to stop the downward force of my chair possibly breaking it again, i tied a cable to the part where the seat and spine meet to the broken leg

Comment: Considering the weight placed on a chair, this seems like an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm happy this is working for you _for now_, but do take care, zip-ties, while one of the greatest marvels of the modern world, aren't designed to take a lot of weight and will give up on you without much warning. As noted in the other answers, something will need to be added to the leg to take the strain. A piece of pipe _inside_ the leg, held in place with a complete sleeve of zip-ties _might_ do the trick...

Answer (score -2):

you have to make hole on either side (top hole on broken part ,top hole on stationary part , side wise hole on both side of both part) then take a strong metal strip which contain small hole on both the end. then joint this stationary and broken part with strip and NUT BOLT combination THAT's IS TS's DONE

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you edit your answer to make it more clear as to what you're suggesting, as it's not very clear right now?